# Spanish Characters in HTML Page Title

Tags: html, utf-8

My HTML code for Page title looks like this

```
<title>Telefonía</title>
```

When i check it on browser the SPanish character is not displayed exactly like the above

It shows page title as below

[image]

I tried using **& iacute;**  AND
**&# 237; ** but it doesnt work in PAGE TITLE

Here is my [website url](http://www.infrasistemas.com.uy/SearchResults.asp?Cat=25) i checked all the special codes but it doesnt work

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: have you tried this ??   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: or <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: @PavanK tried but doesnt work please check it at http://tinyurl.com/agdsqff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing

> `&iacute;`

instead. These are HTML escape characters. Here you can find a whole list http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Comment: Interesting. Did you just try to write the title with í in a normal way? I tested using the developer tools and copied the character and it appeared correctly!

Answer (score 16):

This works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Telefonía</title>
</head>
```

Comment: It works through firebug if you just copy+paste it i think but when i do a view source it shows <title>Telefon&#195;&#173;a</title> so would it be good if i do a find replace of those character using JQuery or something?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

and if you want change your title dynamically in you .js put:

```
document.title="telefonía";
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm to check how you should encode special characters.

In this case it would be `&#237;` or `&Iacute;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check two things:

1. Your file encoding. Yes, your HTML file. You have to save it as UTF-8 and then write "í" or whatever character you need.
2. Your `<meta>` tag. It should look like:

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Un saludo!

Comment: If you are using PHP, you have to save the PHP file as UTF-8. Please, write "Telefonía" and let me know what happens (now I see &iacute; in your page)

Comment: its ASP and i dont have the source code for this hosted solution so i can change only the page title and meta tags

Comment: if you are writing "Telefonía" and it is not working then it is likely a problem of the CMS you are using. Maybe it is storing the title in a database table with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The element `<title>Telefonía</title>` works just fine, provided that the document is saved in UTF-8 encoding (which is the encoding declared in an HTTP header sent by the server – no `meta` tag inside the document can override that).

You seem to be changing the content of [your page](http://www.infrasistemas.com.uy/SearchResults.asp?Cat=25) trying various ways that cannot work, such as `<title>Telefon&iacute;a</title>` and `<title>Telefoniacute;a</title>`. If you use an entity reference, you should write `<title>Telefon&iacute;a</title>`. But there is no need for that: using the character as such is cleaner and simpler

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation unfortunately i dont have the ASP page code Access i can do 2 things only change page title and add Javascript or Jquery to change the page title so there is no way in html to override it you mean ?

Comment: There’s little point in changing the title with JavaScript, since the `title` element is essential to search engines, and they can’t be expected to run JavaScript. If the title text you enter does not get saved in the document’s encoding, then the issue is with your authoring environment and should be asked as such.

Answer (score 0):

All solution here
HTML Codes for Spanish Language Characters
https://www.thoughtco.com/html-codes-spanish-characters-4062194

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p>Telefon&#237a</p>
```

is the hex code for it.
&iacute works as well
http://jsfiddle.net/PDCvw/
EDIT
It appears to work for me in the title. A link is http://shodor.org/~amalani/acute.html
You have the code

```
<title>Telefon&amp;iacute;a</title>
```

but what you need is 
    Telefon&iacutea

Telefonía